# Debugging CoreGraphics crashes with no reference to app code

Tags: c++, ios, core-graphics, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have had an app on the AppStore since 2011 and since then the app has gone through quite a few changes as you might expect, after the last change I have started receiving some crashes (I use Crashlytics) that seem to indicate that the source is CoreGraphics although it must be something that I'm doing wrong with it, and not the library itself, but since the crashes themselves do not contain any code that refers to my app it's a bit complicated to know what it could be.

I can't seem to be able to trigger this issue but some users can, I've checked and some of them had enough memory so it's not an out of memory issue afaik.

The only crashes I have received are all this one in particular so it's not a red herring due to some memory issues that may trigger false positives. The app is constantly used and tested with Address sanitizer on so it should catch all of these.

I'm fairly well versed in C++ (the main language of the app) but know just enough Objective-C to get things done so I was wondering if I am missing something or if there is a way to debug this, since I wouldn't even know where to start.

Since I can't trigger the issue, and I can't see where it happens, I can't think of any way of sorting this out.

What would be the best way of debugging this, how do people approach this?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x184079b80 _platform_memmove + 176
1  CoreGraphics                   0x185bc81f8 decode_data + 12740
2  CoreGraphics                   0x185bc81f8 decode_data + 12740
3  CoreGraphics                   0x185d982f4 img_decode_read + 2032
4  CoreGraphics                   0x185d9bffc img_alphamerge_read + 548
5  CoreGraphics                   0x185d9f818 img_data_lock + 7048
6  CoreGraphics                   0x185d9dc38 CGSImageDataLock + 184
7  CoreGraphics                   0x185bbe704 ripc_AcquireRIPImageData + 308
8  CoreGraphics                   0x185db287c ripc_DrawImage + 644
9  CoreGraphics                   0x185da2678 CGContextDrawImageWithOptions + 632
10 QuartzCore                     0x188335f7c CA::Render::(anonymous namespace)::create_image_by_rendering(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double) + 1232
11 QuartzCore                     0x188336f60 CA::Render::(anonymous namespace)::create_image_from_rgb_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double) + 676
12 QuartzCore                     0x1883358e4 CA::Render::create_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double) + 900
13 QuartzCore                     0x188338584 CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double, double) + 472
14 QuartzCore                     0x18843ebcc -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) _copyRenderLayer:layerFlags:commitFlags:] + 632
15 QuartzCore                     0x1884434b0 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 444
16 QuartzCore                     0x1883a7dcc CA::Context::commit_root(CA::Layer*, void*) + 44
17 QuartzCore                     0x188366fd8 x_hash_table_foreach + 72
18 QuartzCore                     0x1883a8674 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 2208
19 QuartzCore                     0x1883ce340 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540
20 QuartzCore                     0x1883cf180 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1843ff8b8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1843fd270 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1843fd82c __CFRunLoopRun + 1292
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18431e2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
25 GraphicsServices               0x1861aff84 GSEventRunModal + 100
26 UIKit                          0x18d8cb880 UIApplicationMain + 208
27 (MyAppName)                    0x1010cb280 main (main.m:14)
28 libdyld.dylib                  0x183e4256c start + 4
```